# Allocating memory in stack via "Value Template Argument" vs. regular array

Tags: c++, templates, stack

I'm studying [*A Tour of C++*](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/a-tour-of/9780134998053/ch06.xhtml) and one of the demonstrations for **Value Template Argument** is to create a template class to arbitrarily allocate Buffer in the stack. I fail to see how it is different than simply create an array (i.e. int buf[100]) which will also be allocated from the stack?

> Value arguments are useful in many contexts. For example, Buffer
>   allows us to create arbitrarily sized buffers with no use of the free
>   store (dynamic memory):

```
Buffer<char,1024> glob;  // global buffer of characters (statically allocated)

void fct()
{
     Buffer<int,10> buf; // local buffer of integers (on the stack)
     // ...
}
```

Comment: C arrays have all sorts of problem behaviours (decaying to pointers etc); See also `std::array` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: One thing that is different is the lifetime of the objects. `buf` only lives inside `fct`. `glob` lives until `main` returns and global objects are destroyed.

Comment: It's a custom type, so you can have methods like checked[],`begin`, `end`, `size` that don't go away when passing the array by reference to another function

Comment: I guess, the book is pre-c++11. Nowadays this `Buffer` is spelled `std::array`.

Comment: The link references lambda expressions, so it's C++11-or-newer. Stroustrup is probably easing the reader into `std::array`. If I'm wrong, [here's a link to a newer rev](https://isocpp.org/tour).

Comment: Thanks everyone for your ideas, I grasped several differences including pointer decay and extend abilities of containers vs c array.

Comment: The book I’m reading is the updated edition so some of the hypothesis seem reasonable too. I’ll watch out for std:array in the future chapters:)

Comment: Finally, I got to chapter 13.4.1 and Mr. Stroustrup gave several good examples on why prefer std::array over C-style array and how sometimes std::array has performance advantage to vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably the `Buffer` template class is similar to what's provided by [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

The **big difference** is, that with a class, all kinds of additional operations can be added, besides from raw c-style arrays, which cannot have any operators or other benefits you can use with classes.

Comment: I'd say, the biggest difference would be with the fact that `Buffer` can be passed by value, but c-array can not.

Comment: @SergeyA Well, that's _one_ of the advantages. There are many others though.

Comment: Everything else can be emulated. Yes, you can't have functions as members of C arrays, but you can certainly create the functions which take those arrays as arguments (by reference, for example) and effectively it would be the same thing.